# C# Regular Expression to skip some special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I am newbie to Regex and trying to learn that. My requirement is to ONLY consider a string as valid if it has JUST small alphabets, absolutely nothing else.
ex: abc, khj, sdfs are valid words but Abc, KHJ,123,a$bd are not valid.

I am writing a regular expression like this:

```
 private bool IsValid(string str)
 {
    Regex r = new Regex(@"[a-z][^<>%'=\$]");
    Console.WriteLine(str + " : " + r.IsMatch(str).ToString()); 
    return r.IsMatch(str);
 }
```

But when I pass on the following input to this method:

```
"a<>'b=b"
 "abc"
 "a$b"
"123"
"IHH"
```

it is identifying `abc` as valid but it is also recognizing `a$b` and `a<>'b=b` as valid words ! (returning `true` for those)
I want to understand how to skip `a$b` and `a<>'b=b ??` the method should return `false` for them.

Please help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this kind of method with an appropriate pattern:

```
private bool IsValid(string str)
 {
    Regex r = new Regex(@"^[a-z]+$");
    Console.WriteLine(str + " : " + r.IsMatch(str).ToString()); 
    return r.IsMatch(str);
 }
```

Comment: I am trying this one, it gives me "false" for every input now. even for abc,def etc.

Comment: Correction, it works. I was passing an extra space by mistake as input to the method. I trimmed it out and it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will look like

```
var pat = /^[a-z]+$/;
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work. It gives false for every input (even abc, def etc)

Answer (score 0):

Good Reference: [RegEx Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/cheatsheet.aspx)

Try this: `^[a-z]+$`

Comment: I am trying this one, it gives me "false" for every input now. even for abc,def etc.

Comment: Correction, it works. I was passing an extra space by mistake as input to the method. I trimmed it out and it works. Thanks a lot.